# How can I update column values from one table with unique values from another?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have 2 tables T1 and T2 and need to update T2.F with unique values from T1.F
How can I do this in Microsoft Access 2013 through SQL or VBA currentdb.execute?

```
T1.F T2.F
A      A
A      B
B
B
B
C
C
C
C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO T2(F)
SELECT DISTINCT T1.F
FROM T1
```

- `T2(F)` - F is your column name in table T2.
- `SELECT DISTINCT` gets    the different values in T1.F (A, B, C, etc)

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked ideally!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will actually work but surely if you're looking at the SQL to run (through whichever interface you choose) something like the following would work:

```
INSERT INTO t2
SELECT DISTINCT
    columnName
FROM
   t1
   LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.columnName = t2.columnName 
WHERE
   t2.columnName IS NULL
```